# How to get grails 3.x to respond to an OPTIONS request?

Tags: grails-3.0

In grails 2.x, we had to add this to the `src/templates/war/web.xml` in order for it to route an `OPTIONS` request.  These types of requests are used when CORS is used.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

web.xml isn't used anymore in grails 3 so there must be a new way.  I'm also curious why this option doesn't default on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the new way to configure is in `resources.groovy`:

```
import org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsDispatcherServlet

beans = {
    // configure dispatch servlet so it dispatches OPTIONS requests
    dispatcherServlet(GrailsDispatcherServlet) {
        dispatchOptionsRequest = true
    }
}
```